# Any machines that use currents in nanoampere?

Tags: electricity

Milliampere and microampere is quiet common in human-made machines, are there examples of machines that use nanoampere currents?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* eric svensson! I'm struggling to find any conceptual physics content in your question as written. You might consider editing it to show some research effort and identify a specific physics related question. I've voted to close your question for the "Not suitable for this site" reason.

Comment: I have an ion implanter that provides one ion at a time. So a nanoamp would be way too high a measure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it is not about any specific physics concept, but rather asks for a very broad range of devices which use nanoampere currents.

Comment: @FakeMod It is a specific physics question but worded a bit broadly. The specific question is, is 260 picoampere sufficient to transmit a signal through a 1 micron wire. Inquired broadly to get a sense of if it was within reasonable bounds. Question overall is general physics concepts.

Comment: The specific question is, if nanoampere currents are sufficient to build useful machines. It asks about scale, most households use 100 amps, light bulbs around 1 amp, nanoampere is a billion times less, and the question is if humans build machines or components in machines that run on nano-scale currents.

Comment: conclusion made was that axons rely on I^2*R, to keep glucose costs low, it is how it can run on so low amperages, https://www.docdroid.net/tolDQPw/the-reverse-of-photosynthesis-as-a-source-for-electric-currents-in-neurons-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Photodiodes generate nanoampere currents in response to light: http://edge.rit.edu/edge/P09051/public/photodiodeamplifers.pdf.

Comment: Why I asked, was wondering if 260 picoampere would be sufficient to transmit a signal through a 1 micron diameter axon. What do you think? https://www.docdroid.net/QzUS2FM/the-reverse-of-photosynthesis-as-a-source-for-electric-currents-in-neurons-pdf

Comment: @ericsvensson The "inverse of photosynthesis" is called respiration, and it does not generate free electrons.

Comment: not looking for debate. combustion of glucose releases 36 electrons. "electron transport" can use those for building different molecules. obviously still can release those 36 electrons for current. so, false statement from you.

Comment: @ericsvensson The equation for respiration is: $\text{C}_6\text{H}_{12}\text{O}_6+6\text{O}_2\to 6\text{CO}_2+6\text{H}_2\text{O}$. The electrons forming covalent bonds in glucose are rearranged to form the covalent bonds in water and carbon dioxide. They don't become free electrons at the end; you can count the electrons on each side yourself if you like.

Comment: as mentioned, not looking for debate. of course, 36 electrons in glucose compared to water and carbon dioxide can be released not into building other compounds but as electric current.

Comment: @ericsvensson Where does the number 36 even come from, anyway? There are $(4\times 6)+(1\times 12)+(6\times 6)=72$ electrons in the valence shell of glucose and $6\times(2\times 6)=72$ electrons in the valence shells of the six oxygen molecules, while there are $6\times (4+2\times 6)=96$ electrons in the valence shells of the six carbon dioxide molecules and $6\times (2\times 1+6)=48$ electrons in the valence shells of the six water molecules. This works out to $72+72=144$ valence electrons in the reactants and $96+48=144$ valence electrons in the products. Where is the 36?

Comment: difference in electrons before hydrocarbon (carbon dioxide and water) and after (glucose and oxygen), in anabolic processes those electrons are also used so usually you get around 36 ATP or so, etc

Comment: @ericsvensson Glucose isn't a hydrocarbon. It contains oxygen, while hydrocarbons contain only hydrogen and carbon. Also, ATP isn't produced by transferring electrons from glucose. It's produced in the reaction $\text{ADP}^{3-}+\text{PO}_4^{3-}+2\text{H}^+\to \text{ATP}^{4-}+\text{H}_2\text{O}$, catalyzed by ATP synthase. Once again, the number of electrons are balanced on each side of the equation - it doesn't need external electrons to proceed, only energy and the catalyst enzyme.

Comment: well carbohydrate more often used. obviously release of 36 electrons besides anabolic processes can and could also be used for long-range electric current, goes without saying. not looking for debate, feel free